# MVC3 Razor and the browser (IE9) back button issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, browser, razor

I am developing a MVC 3 Razor app and I'm having issues when I click the back button in the browser. My application workflow:

1. Select a facility from a dropdown list
2. A WebGrid gets populated with a list of the facility's buildings.
3. Click an image to edit a building
4. Click the browser's back button and the dropdown list in step 1 appears without the CSS formatting. If I click F5 to refresh then everything resets and the CSS formatting is back.

I'm using VS2010 and the ASP.NET development server with IE9 as the default browser. I have added the OutputCache attribute to every ActionResult in the controller.

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

Here's my link in the WebGrid built from a PartialView

```
    grid.Column(header: "", 
            format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "BuildingModels", new { @id = item.FACInventoriesId })"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/edit.png")"
                alt='Edit' title='Edit'  border='0'/></a></text>)
```

How do I get a browser to show the WebGrid (step 2) when the back button is click from editing a building (step 4)? Also any ideas why the CSS formatting is missing when I click the back button?

Here's the Controller code:

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Systems = buildingsVM.GetSystemsList();

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult GetFacilityDetails(int systemId, string facilityId)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.Systems = buildingsVM.GetSystemsList();

            var facility = buildingsVM.GetFacilityDetails(systemId, facilityId);

            facility.Buildings = buildingsVM.GetFacilityBuildings(systemId, facilityId);

            var bldgsHtml = ViewsUtility.RenderPartialViewToString(this, "_Buildings", facility.Buildings);

            TempData["CurrentFacility"] = facility;
            return Json(new { ok = true, facdata = facility, bldgs = bldgsHtml, message = "ok" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { ok = false, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult GetSystemFacilities(int systemId)
    {
        try
        {
            var facilities = buildingsVM.GetFacilitesBySystemId(systemId);
            return Json(new { ok = true, data = facilities, message = "ok" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { ok = false, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var facility = TempData["CurrentFacility"] as FacilityModel;

        return View(buildingsVM.GetBuilding(id));
    }
```

Code from Partial View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<COPSPlanningWeb.Models.BuildingModel>
    <!-- Current Buildings from partial view -->
    @{              
    if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
    {
    var grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: 50, defaultSort: "BuildingNumber");  //ajaxUpdateContainerId: "tabs-2", 

    grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: Model.Count(), autoSortAndPage: false);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgridDisplay",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        //grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID, ContactID = item.ContactID })), 
        grid.Column("BuildingNumber", header: "Building Number", style: "webgridDisplayCenter"),
        grid.Column("ConstructionDate", header: "Construction Date", format: @<text>@item.ConstructionDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</text>),
        grid.Column("ExtSquareFeet", header: "Exterior Sq. Ft.", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:n0}", item.ExtSquareFeet)),
        grid.Column("IntSquareFeet", header: "Interior Sq. Ft.", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:n0}", item.IntSquareFeet)),
        grid.Column("IU_Avail", header: "IU Available"),
        grid.Column("SpaceAvail", header: "Space Available"),
        grid.Column("FixedAssetValue", header: "Fixed Asset Value", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:C}", item.FixedAssetValue)),
        grid.Column("FixedEquipValue", header: "Fixed Equipment Value", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:C}", item.FixedEquipValue)),
        grid.Column(header: "", 
            format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "BuildingModels", new { @id = item.FACInventoriesId })"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/edit.png")"
                alt='Edit' title='Edit'  border='0'/></a></text>),
        grid.Column(header: "", 
            format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "BuildingModels", new { @id = item.FACInventoriesId })"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/trash.png")"
                alt='Delete' title='Delete'  border='0'/></a></text>)
   ))
   }
   }
```

Code from Edit view:

```
    @model COPSPlanningWeb.Models.BuildingModel
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Add/Edit Inventory";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table style="width: 100%;" class="display">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FacilityId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FACInventoriesId)
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">
            Building Information - Edit Inventory
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Facility Name
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">

        </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Building Number
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuildingNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BuildingNumber)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Construction Date
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConstructionDate, "DateTime")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConstructionDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Exterior Sq. Ft.
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExtSquareFeet)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExtSquareFeet)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Interior Sq. Ft.
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IntSquareFeet)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IntSquareFeet)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            IU Available
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IU_Avail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IU_Avail)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Space Available
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SpaceAvail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpaceAvail)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Fixed Asset Value
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FixedAssetValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FixedAssetValue)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Fixed Equipment Value
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FixedEquipValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FixedEquipValue)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Total Fixed Asset Value
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalFixedAssetValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalFixedAssetValue)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fieldlabel">
            Total Fixed Equipment Value
        </td>
        <td class="fielddata">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalFixedEquipValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalFixedEquipValue)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table class="display" style="text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Add/Edit Spaces", "Index")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="button" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Back to Buildings List", "Index")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
       </tr>

     </table>
    }
```

When I click the back button from the Edit view I expected to see the WebGrid again (building list), but instead I get the first view without any CSS formatting.

Thanks to Luis I was able to resolve the CSS formatting issue, but I'm still not seeing the WebGrid when I click the back button. I'm using JSON to populate the WebGrid could this be the problem? Should I use a form post after the item in the dropdown has been selected?

Comment: Please provide a full sample allowing us to reproduce the problem: Model, View and Controller code. With sample values of course, narrowed down as much as possible, so that we don't have to setup a database or whatever in order to repro. Thank you.

Comment: If you test that in other browsers, do you see the same problem?

Comment: I'm developing an intranet application and everyone uses IE9

Answer (score 3):

Something similar happened to me making an app for the intranet... but hey cheer up, at least your company uses IE9... I had to make miracles trying to make a MVC3 Razor app with JQuery work with IE7...

Ok now to what's important, I had a similar issue with the cache of IE, it appears that the cache of this browser works "differently" from the normal-new-age browsers, you could try this:

Press F12 and go to the tab `Cache` and check `Always refresh from server`

Then check if everything works as it should do, if it does, tell your network administrator to make a new policy for all the IE browsers that are going to use this new app you're making.

Also check this https://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks that did help a little. I do see the first view with it's CSS formatting, but I still don't see the WebGrid when I click the browser's back button which would be the expected behavior. Is there some coding I must do in order get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Location to the attribute to get this to work with IE9

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```